Mono output instead of Stereo Beelink mini s12 PRO
I have a Beelink Mini s12 PRO computer and I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
The sound is only MONO. I use a HDMI port for image and sound and a TV as monitor.
I installed Pulse Audio Volume Control and PAVUCONTROL but doesn't solve the problem.
This is my computer:
H/W path           Device     Class          Description

                              system         MINI S (01)
/0                            bus            MINI S
/0/0                          memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/27                         memory         16GiB System Memory
/0/27/0                       memory         16GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3200 
/0/27/1                       memory         [empty]
/0/32                         memory         128KiB L1 cache
/0/33                         memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/34                         memory         2MiB L2 cache
/0/35                         memory         6MiB L3 cache
/0/36                         processor      Intel(R) N100
/0/100                        bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/2           /dev/fb0   display        Alder Lake-N [UHD Graphics]
/0/100/14                     bus            Alder Lake-N PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host 
/0/100/14/0        usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1      input3     input          Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transcei
/0/100/14/0/a                 communication  AX201 Bluetooth
/0/100/14/1        usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14.2                   memory         RAM memory
/0/100/14.3        wlo1       network        CNVi: Wi-Fi
/0/100/15                     bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/15.1                   bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/16                     communication  Alder Lake-N PCH HECI Controller
/0/100/17          scsi0      storage        Intel Corporation
/0/100/17/0.0.0    /dev/sda   disk           512GB FORESEE 512GB SS
/0/100/17/0.0.0/1             volume         99MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/17/0.0.0/2  /dev/sda2  volume         127MiB reserved partition
/0/100/17/0.0.0/3  /dev/sda3  volume         117GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/17/0.0.0/4  /dev/sda4  volume         1767MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/17/0.0.0/5  /dev/sda5  volume         29GiB Linux swap volume
/0/100/17/0.0.0/6  /dev/sda6  volume         327GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/19                     bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/19.1                   bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c                     bridge         Intel Corporation
/0/100/1c/0        enp1s0     network        RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express 
/0/100/1e                     communication  Intel Corporation
/0/100/1e.3                   bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f                     bridge         Alder Lake-N PCH eSPI Controller
/0/100/1f/0                   system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/1                   communication  PnP device PNP0501
/0/100/1f/2                   system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/3                   system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/4                   system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/5                   system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f/6                   system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/100/1f.3        card0      multimedia     Alder Lake-N PCH High Definition Au
/0/100/1f.3/0      input10    input          HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
/0/100/1f.3/1      input11    input          HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
/0/100/1f.3/2      input12    input          HDA Intel PCH Line
/0/100/1f.3/3      input13    input          HDA Intel PCH Line Out
/0/100/1f.3/4      input14    input          HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
/0/100/1f.3/5      input15    input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/0/100/1f.3/6      input16    input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/0/100/1f.3/7      input17    input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
/0/100/1f.3/8      input18    input          HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
/0/100/1f.4                   bus            Intel Corporation
/0/100/1f.5                   bus            Intel Corporation
/1                            power          Default string
/2                            power          Default string
/3                            power          Default string
/4                 input0     input          Sleep Button
/5                 input1     input          Power Button
/6                 input2     input          Power Button
/7                 input9     input          Video Button

How can I solve the problem?
Thank you!

Does the HDMI port on the computer support stereo sound? Does the TV support HDMI stereo sound input? Does the HDMI cable being used handle video and stereo sound? Suggest you verify the hardware supports what you are trying to do.

I shall boot the computer with Widows and find out if there is a problem with the sound to. But the TV suports stereo input. The cable can handle video and stereo sound output.

On Windows the sound is stereo, the cable , the TV and the hardware are capabale of delivering stereo sound.
